# How to install angular 2 with npm 3.8.9 and node 0.10.25

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular

I am trying to install angular 2 on my ubuntu machine and I've npm version 3.8.9 and 0.10.25.

I follow https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

in my friends windows machine with npm version 2.11.x it install less modules and also create typings folder but with same commands in my system it install so many modules also its not creating any typings folder.

and also its not working as per quick start guide

what I've to do to run angular 2 with my configuration and is there any direct way like angular 1 to just include library and start working if not please let me know how to run it in any way.

Comment: ya you do without npm

Comment: ask your friend to run this command `npm update -g npm` or `npm install -g npm` it will update npm to latest version

Comment: but its working on his system not in mine @Bender

Comment: please let me know how any source or link @uzaif

Comment: okey i will give link

Comment: @MohitBumb this is due to version difference in NPM i guess , you both need to update your `npm` and then run this `npm install angular2`

Comment: I tried this command http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/1271944/dfdb72d3c6349337496ca6def63db1dc @Bender

Comment: How about to use a ready boilerplate Angular 2? https://github.com/mschwarzmueller/angular-2-beta-boilerplate

Comment: checkout this plunk i implemented CRUD https://embed.plnkr.co/OUzjcNMbacE8F4MfGLaj/

Comment: @MohitBumb checkout my code on plunker let me know if it useful or not

Comment: thanks I can include it directly cool it really helps @uzaif

Comment: @Mikhail thanks I'm cloning it :)

Answer (score 1):

Angular 2 Installation Process For Ubuntu:

*Type this command one by one in Terminal*

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
node -v (for nodejs version check)
sudo apt-get install npm
npm -v (for npm version check)
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

To create a new project

```
ng new (your-project-name)
ng serve       // run project
```

Answer (score 0):

For this case, you have to set up one virtual environment for Development Like [Docker](https://github.com/wsargent/docker-cheat-sheet) or [Virtual Box](https://gist.github.com/rosswd/b9f1c2d1215e5f55c685) etc

Choose the proper version for any dependencies you want.

You both can work with the same configuration.